# Is JQuery or Javascript capable for image processing?

Tags: php, jquery

My plan is to develop a web based application in the future. I think I can name it "Booth Reservation System" for the Events companies here in our country. One of the main functionality of the system and the most tricky part/difficult part is that the user can upload a "floor plan" (the design of the area were the booth is located in any image format) and then select the specific location on the floor plan to reserve to the booth. Also, the user can create a floor plan on the system.

What do you think? What programming language can I use?

Comment: What you describe isn't image processing.

Comment: I want the system more user friendly that the user need not to install any application in order to run the system. Maybe one of my example is "wikimapia.org" you can tag the location of your home office etc. i want something like that that the user can easily access the system functionality without worrying to install any third party application. Maybe facebook.com is also an example because you can tag your photos and crop your photos. I think this project is very very hard to accomplished but maybe i need to put my self to the limit.

Comment: continuation.. This project also I think will satisfy me as a programmer. When I successfully developed this project, i think this will be useful for the companies that needed that kind of business application. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of sites and documentation out there to make things like maps and the like with javascript and images.

I would use javascript. Google Maps is based on this.

First;
You need a canvas, then...

using `getImageData()` and `putImageData()` will help you with the image part.

see my page at [fracturedcode](http://www.fracturedcode.com/archives/53). I hope it can be useful to you.

Comment: | Thanks man for your suggestion. I already visited your site! nice work! amazing! Its clear for me now that javascript is also capable of handling this functionality. I think I need to spend my time practicing javascript to accomplished the task. Nice work man. thank you!

Comment: you might also need to use some PHP for handling user uploads

Answer (score 0):

Getting javascript do the image processing is a bit of a push. html5 with javascript supports FFT, but getting it to do what you are planning seems a notch too high.

If you are uploading it to a server, you may do some image processing with php, perl or python  - These are much better at image processing than javascript.

If a person draws a layout on a paper with hand and uploads a scanned copy, your system may not be able to process it. I'd think it might be just okay to limit the options to some popular formats.

The booth selection seems no different from the airline seat selection interface.

Comment: | Is java is also applicable for this type of task for image processing?

Comment: @adietan63 Most languages will do, but I would really suggest alternatives

Comment: @adietan63 - I believe so. I remember seeing a few libraries for image processing in java too.

Answer (score 0):

Allowing users to upload custom floor plans and processing them will be a tough proposition. You'll have to find a way to automate the process of finding the booth, delimiting each booth.

If you provide your own floor plans, it should be relatively easy to find do find the co-ordinates of mouse click and then find the corresponding booth.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is just a language, but the popular implementations inside web browsers aren't really suitable for actual image processing, simply because they lack the I/O possibilities. (You could substitute an ajax interface for data storage, and you could inspect image data at the binary level in javascript, constructing data URIs on the fly, but this is way too much hassle to be feasible, especially since you'll never get the kind of performance you need).

However, what you describe isn't really image processing anyway; what you want is vector graphics support, and the javascript implementations in newer browsers all provide that. You have two choices: SVG and canvas. Both can do what you describe, including a click-and-point vector graphics editor. It's a complex task, but perfectly feasible.

If you want users to be able to upload floor plans, rather than edit them inside your web app, you'll have to be able to parse the vector graphics format of choice (SVG in this case seems quite appropriate; Adobe's toolchain supports it, and for user that cannot afford them, Inkscape is a free editor with native SVG support). Putting an SVG image on your page and making individual elements clickable isn't too hard. Since SVG is XML-based, you could even throw a bit of simple XSLT at it to add the links; or you could go a bit fancier and provide an interactive link editor.

If you want to support IE 8 and older (which doesn't have SVG support, but instead uses its own VML vector graphics format), you may want to look into [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/).

Comment: Thank you for sharing your ideas :) .But I want the system more user friendly that the user need not to install any application in order to run the system. Maybe one of my example is "wikimapia.org" you can tag the location of your home office etc. i want something like that that the user can easily access the system functionality without worrying to install any third party application. Maybe facebook.com is also an example because you can tag your photos and crop your photos. I think this project is very very hard to accomplished but maybe i need to put my self to the limit.

Comment: continuation.. This project also I think will satisfy me as a programmer. When I successfully developed this project, i think this will be useful for the companies that needed that kind of business application. :)